# Array formula with SUM Function returns incorrect result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have some data of transactions, for example as following:

```
Column B|Column C

TRUCK_ID|TON

TR-12   |60

TR-10   |65

TR-09   |56

TR-12   |75

TR-10   |70
```

*in reality I have thousands data

Then I would like to count how many truck that loads overcapacity, where
the load limit as following:

```
Column F|Column G   
TR-09|50

TR-10|60

TR-12|65
```

I use a combination of SUM, IF, INDEX, MATCH and ROW

```
=SUM(IF(C4:C8>INDEX(G4:G6,MATCH(INDEX(B4:B8,ROW(B4:B8)-3),F4:F6,0)),1))
```

But when I only select one (single) cell and click CSE

it returns '2' (incorrect)

If I select multi cells (let say 2 cells) and click CSE

it returns '4' (correct)

I expect I only put and select one single cell only and return the correct result. Anybody could help me, please

Comment: I just found a work-around for your original formula. Check my updated solution for the details. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B6=TRANSPOSE(F2:F4))*(C2:C6>TRANSPOSE(G2:G4)))
```

Note: This is an array formula and need to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

You could also add one helper column, in `H2` put:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$6,F2,$C$2:$C$6,">"&G2)
```

And drag down, to sum H2:H at the end.

---

***Screenshot*** `SUMPRODUCT`:

[image]

***Screenshot*** Helper column:

[image]

Comment: Hi..thank you for trying to help me. I tried as you suggested =SUMPRODUCT((B2:B6=TRANSPOSE(F2:F4))*(C2:C6>TRANSPOSE(G2:G4))) but I returned 3, not 4..it should be 4. I didn't expect helper column in this case anyway

Comment: My initial formula did work well when I SELECT multiple cell before pressing CSE. I just had no idea why it didn't work correctly when I ONLY select one cell before pressing CSE.

Comment: @NurHolis, check updated answer, it does work for me :)

Comment: Hi @JvdV .. I really thank you for helping me. Yeah, I retry and see it works. By the way, which part did you update? I didn't see something changed in the formula you shared.

Comment: Hi @JvdV, I have just tried your formula in another case, and yes I see it very powerful. But I have no idea to understand how the formula works. Would you please enlighten me.

Comment: @nurholis, look at it like a matrix. The Sumproduct takes each row in the table and checks that against a row of values (hence the transpose) to return an array of true and false. Multiply that by the same type of matrix but than the load limits would return 1's and zeros. Which will tell us if the truck is overloaded. Finally the Sumproduct will add all these 1s and 0s. Best is to step through the formula using evaluation in excel. It's a build in feature. It will show step by step what I tried to explain poorly haha. Btw, if this helped please consider to mark the answer as answered. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT#2**

Try modify your original formula as below:

```
=SUM(IF(C4:C8>INDEX(G4:G6,MATCH(INDEX(B4:B8,N(IF(1,ROW(B4:B8)))-3),F4:F6,0)),1))
```

> Use **N** and **IF** function can actually overcome the issue of INDEX only returning the first value from the range in a single cell.

Alternatively, suppose you have the following **named ranges**:

- **Truck_ID** being data in Column B;
- **TON** being data in Column C;
- **List_ID** being data in Column F;
- **List_TON** being data in Column G.

[image: Solution]

You can use the following formula to return the desired result `4` presume **the look-up table is sorted in ascending order**:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LOOKUP(Truck_ID,List_ID,List_TON)<TON))
```

or

```
{=SUM(IF((LOOKUP(Truck_ID,List_ID,List_TON)<TON),1))} 'Entered by CSE as array formula
```

> Your **INDEX** function `INDEX(G4:G6,MATCH(INDEX(B4:B8,ROW(B4:B8)-3),F4:F6,0))` is returning a single-column array, which will only return the first value from the array which is `65` **in a single cell**. So your full formula is essentially comparing each value in **TON** against `65`. As a result there are only `2` values that are greater than `65`. As shown in Column D of my example, a more proper use of **INDEX** in this case would be highlighting range `D4:D8` and enter the array formula as shown in the formula bar. Then you can do a **SUM** for all `TRUE` results. If you enter your full formula in multiple cells, your **INDEX** formula will actually return the full array instead of the first value so the comparison will return the correct result.

Comment: Hi @Terry W. First of all, I would like to thank you for sharing your helpful idea. In this case, yes your formula works very well. I actually tried LOOKUP formula before using INDEXMATCH, but I considered limitation of LOOKUP that works well only in ascending range of lookup_range. Will it be good idea if I replace LOOKUP with VLOOKUP at least?

Comment: @NurHolis **VLOOKUP** woks in the similar fashion as **INDEX** in this case, which will return `2` in a single cell but `4` in multiple cells. I would say JvdV's first formula works best.

Comment: yeah the formula JvdV shared works best. I tried it in another case and returns correct result. I just had no Idea how it works especially what TRANSPOSE function does